# Why can't list unpacking be used for indexing a second list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

… e.g. `a[*b]` where `a` and `b` are both lists and `len(b) == 1`

Using the simple example below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [0]

a[*b]
```

Why does running the above raise an exception?

```
    a[*b]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that syntax is invalid.

Iterable unpacking is allowed in various circumstances – for example:

- [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)
- [Assignment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)
- [Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

… but not universally, and definitely not for indexing. In fact, it's unclear what your proposed syntax even means. Consider: what would `a[*b]` return if `b` were `[1, 2]`?